# Odd fusion table map embedding – all red areas

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm developing a fusion table map with filled areas. On the Google Fusion Table web app it works properly ( [link](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1gjBg_x5myM7p609Gz-mBJel5B8VLitg4E29R-Ok#map%3aid=3) ). But when I try to embed it, all the areas come out to be all red ( [link](http://www.datajournalist.it/obiettori/EN_ru486.html) ).

Why is this happening? I've tried to open the site from another computer - but same issue.

Thanks,

Elisa

Comment: Both maps have the same styling when I view them.

Comment: I had already fixed it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [thread in the Fusion Tables Users Group](https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/browse_frm/thread/24cc7a875ebbfeaa#) (and the thread referenced in it) is probably applicable.  There are now multiple styles available in the "new" look, if you don't reference the correct one, you won't get the style you configured.

You may need to set the style id appropriately.  This query sets the style id to 2:

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({ 
  query: { 
    select: locationColumn, 
    from: tableId 
  }, 
  styleId: 2, 
  map: map 
});
```

This is described [in the Fusion Tables Documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#WorkingStyles)

Answer (score 0):

I solved by rolling back to the Classic Look. Please, team, check what is going on with the new look.