# Google Fusion Table Multiple Layer with Checkbox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a Google Fusion table to create a map that allows a user to select multiple color options for a single polygon.  In the attached jsfiddle I've got a working example:

Area 1 has a default gray color and a red Closed color upon selecting the checkbox.  What I'd like is to have the Open checkbox cause Area 1 to become Green. Thus, Area 1 could have 3 possible colors (Gray, Red, or Green).

I've tried duplicating all of the layer information into a layer2 but have had no luck getting this to work.

Thanks for any suggestions.

http://jsfiddle.net/EezcR/9/

```
function initialize() {
    var tableId = '1_k6LlHVA4eJSgsZJ0esbImaA1HG_bgT_SDEOor0';

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.33,-98.76),
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer();
    filterMap(layer, tableId, map);
// Initialize the first layer
    var firstLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: '1_k6LlHVA4eJSgsZJ0esbImaA1HG_bgT_SDEOor0'
      },
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2,
      map: map, 
    });


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('A'),
        'click', function() {
          filterMap(layer, tableId, map);
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('B'),
        'click', function() {
          filterMap(layer, tableId, map);
    });
  }


  // Filter the map based on checkbox selection.
  function filterMap(layer, tableId, map) {
    var where = generateWhere();

    if (where) {
      if (!layer.getMap()) {
        layer.setMap(map);
      }
      layer.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: 'geometry',
          from: tableId,
          where: where
        }
      });
    } else {
      layer.setMap(null);
    }
  }

  // Generate a where clause from the checkboxes. If no boxes
  // are checked, return an empty string.
  function generateWhere() {
    var filter = [];
    var stores = document.getElementsByName('store');
    for (var i = 0, store; store = stores[i]; i++) {
      if (store.checked) {
        var storeName = store.value.replace(/'/g, '\\\'');
        filter.push("'" + storeName + "'");
      }
    }
    var where = '';
    if (filter.length) {
      where = "'name' IN (" + filter.join(',') + ')';
    }
    return where;
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);





    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

<div>Area 1:
  <input type="checkbox"  name="store"
      id="A" value="A">
  <label>Closed</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="store"
      id="C" value="C">
  <label>Open</label>

</div>
  <div>Area 2:
  <input type="checkbox"  name="store"
      id="B" value="B">
  <label>Closed</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="store"
      id="D" value="D">
  <label>Open</label>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you aware of the limitations on FusionTablesLayer? `You can use the Maps API to add up to five Fusion Tables layers to a map, one of which can be styled with up to five styling rules.`

Comment: I have read about those limitations.  My challenge is figuring out how to get multiple layers applied to one shape. How can I use layer.setOptions to generate up to 5 styling rules? Each time I've tried adding a second layer, that layer becomes the default color rather than selectable based on a checkbox selection.

Comment: That limitation says only one layer can be styled at a time.  The documentation includes an example with multiple styling rules applied to one table.

Comment: Your example of using 3 checkboxes seems to be most like what I need. This link: http://www.geocodezip.com/insight-projects_com_pedc_A.html. I'm currently trying to modify the code I used in my example to match this method.

Comment: Geocode, Can you take a look at this code http://jsfiddle.net/EezcR/11/  I'm really close to getting this right. Where I'm having trouble now, the style of the tables I'm using aren't applying.  How do you insert Styleid for each table so that i'm able to choose what colors each table should have. In the source of your example, I don't see any reference to Styleid.  Thanks for getting me this far!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082518/odd-fusion-table-map-embedding-all-red-areas/14110973#14110973

Comment: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/style_and_template_ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I read your requirements what you need are not multiple layers, you need multiple  styles for a single layer.

- 1 query that selects all stores
- 1 default-style(gray) for all stores
- 1 style(red) for closed stores
- 1 style(green) for open stores

This will not hit any limitations. A sample style would look like this:

```
  [ //default
    {"polygonOptions":{"fillColor":"#919191",
                       "fillOpacity":0.5}
    },
    //open
   {"polygonOptions":{"fillColor":"#00ff00"},
    "where":"'name' IN ('names','of','open','stores')"},
    //closed
   {"polygonOptions":{"fillColor":"#ff0000"},
    "where":"'name' IN ('names','of','closed','stores')"}
  ]
```

Demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4h2S5/**